# Proof problem about continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Problem: A function $f$ is defined on the interval $[0,5]$ by the rule $f(x)=1/x$ and $f(0)=100$. Prove $f$ is not continuous at $(0,100)$.

I know that a function is continuous at a point $p=(x,y)$ based off this definition if and only if

p is a point on $f$ and
if $ϵ>0,$ then there is a $δ>0$ so that if $t$ is in the domain of $f$ and $|t−x|<δ,$ then $|f(t)−f(x)|<ϵ.$

How would I justify this in a formal proof?

Comment: You asked the same question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510125/definition-of-continuity-proof  - why delete and repost?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varepsilon=1$. For each $\delta>0$, pick a number $x>0$ such that $x<\delta$ and that $x\leqslant\frac1{101}$. Then $|x|<\delta$, $x\in D_f$ and$$\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|\geqslant101-100=1=\varepsilon.$$So, I proved that$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x\in D_f):|x|<\delta\wedge\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$which is the negation of the assertion that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition you're given:

> $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $t$ in the domain of $f$, $|t-x| < \delta \implies |f(t) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

The negation is:

> $f$ is **not** continuous at $x$ if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists $t$ in the domain of $f$ with $|t-x| < \delta$ but $|f(t) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$.

For your particular problem,

> $f$ is not continuous at $0$ if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists $t$ with $0 < t < \delta$ but $|f(t) - 100| \geq \epsilon$.

Intuitively, we know $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x) = +\infty$, so use that to your advantage.  Set $\epsilon=1$.  It would be sufficient to show that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $t$ with $0 < t < \delta$ but $f(t) \geq 101$.  Can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

There is another definition of continuity that works better for this (but is completely equivalent).

We say a function $f : A \to B$ is continuous iff for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ that converges to some limit $L$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(L)$.

So for example let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then $x_n\to 0$, yet $f(x_n) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}= n \to \infty \neq 100 = f(0).$

Thus $f$ cannot be continuous.